# Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I have an event that I fire on a child component (code below)  I am getting the following message:

[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking  event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Since I have both bubbles:false and composed:false I am unsure of why its an issue.  Thanks!!

```
  // this method is used to pass info to the parent so that the list can be refreshed
closeHandlerParent() {
    const myEvent = new CustomEvent('close',{
        //bubbles so I can bubble up two components
      bubbles:false,
      composed:false,
      detail: {
        selectedOwnerId: this.selectedOwnerId,
        selectedEffDate: this.selectedEffDate,
        selectedBrokerId: this.selectedBrokerId,
        selectedMarket: this.selectedMarket,
        filtersPopulated: this.filtersPopulated
      }
    })
    this.dispatchEvent(myEvent)
          //used for spinner
    this.isLoading = false

}
```